# get all frames from within Iframe / check whether iframes content has frames

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page which dynamically loads pages into an iframe. 
I found scripts on the web, which adjust the height of the iframe depending on the height of it's content.
But it does not work if the content page hast (normal)frames itself.

Now I want to check, whether the content page has frames or not, or even better access them so that I can calculate their lenght and then choose the highest length value from the subframes to be to length of my iframe.

Please help without JQuery.
Just plain old Javascript. :-)

Thanks

Comment: @BradGilbert why must i use it? sometime is overkilling use a framework only for a function

Comment: If you say you can't use something, the reason should be in the question. Also as far as I know JQuery is "Just plain old Javascript" with a good API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access the frames property of the window object. it's an array containing all the frames in the current document.

```
// suppose a max of 1 frame each inner frame
function getInnerFrame(win) {
    win = win || window;
    if (win.frames.length > 0)
        return getInnerFrame(win.frames[0]);
    else
        return win;
}
```

EDIT: corrected a very stupid error